# How to create bootable hdd with linux for two different PCs?

Tags: linux, boot, bios, external-hard-drive, acer-aspire

First of all I must say I have no knowledge about this topic. All I have done is follow tutorials around the internet, so pardon me for my ignorance.
With that said lets go to the problem.

Almost half a year ago I installed linux mint 19.2 in a hdd with 160GB to carry it around and use it when ever I needed with different PCs. I never encountered a problem until last week. I have used this hdd with three different laptops now: a xiomi with windows 10, a lenovo and an acer (this 2 with windows 7) and it run beautifully. I was currently working with the Acer, since I no longer have access to the other two. The information of this laptop will be given at the end of the question.

The issue came when I bought a new laptop, it´s an Acer Aspire 3, and I tried to run the hard drive on it, but the bios didn't even detect it. I asked a question ( link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582106/how-to-boot-acer-aspire-3-from-external-drive-with-lunix , here you will also see all the info displayed on the bios of this laptop) and decided to format the drive and reinstall linux mint (now 19.3) and create it as FAT32. Here is some info about the new partitions:

```
samuel@samuel:~$ sudo fdisk -l

[sudo] password for samuel:            
Disk /dev/sda: 149,1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4b474b46

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   1118207   1116160  545M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda2         1118208  40179711  39061504 18,6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3        40179712 296038399 255858688  122G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       296038400 312580095  16541696  7,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 59,2 GiB, 63577260032 bytes, 124174336 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc788203a

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 67110911 67108864  32G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
samuel@samuel:~$ 


samuel@samuel:~$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 149,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   545M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0  18,6G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0   122G  0 part /home
└─sda4   8:4    0   7,9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1  59,2G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1    32G  0 part /media/samuel/MULTIBOOT
samuel@samuel:~$
```

This resolved the problem and it runs perfectly in the new Acer. Now the problem is that I can't run it on my old laptop xD I'm guessing the problem is the same as with the new one: the kind of boot...? If the new bios runs on UEFI, maybe this one is LEGACY...? I don´t know. When I try to run it I get

```
error: unknown filesystem.
entering rescue mode...
```

I have investigated a little about this error and i found this tutorial: https://www.easytechguides.com/error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue.html . I tried to follow it. The partitions that come out with the ls command and their filesystem type shows on the next image.

[Grub rescue mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5TXI.jpg)

As you can see, I don't get what the tutorial says I'm supposed to (point 4. of the easytechguides link). I tried to proceed anyway. And got something similar with what point 4 shows when I got to `ls /`. Another picture with the screen in this moment follows:

[msdos2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4NZh.jpg)

As it can be seen in this last picture, I also entered the `/boot` directory and then `/boot/grub` to look. But I don't know how to proceed here. I'm guessing this `msdos2`is the root partition (the `sda2`shown above). I don't really understand what's happening here. And this is where I stand right now.

My questions are: Is it gonna be possible to be able to run de HDD on both PCs? And if yes, how can I do it?

I leave here all the BIOS displays of the old laptop (you have the ones of the new one in the first link of this question).

[OldAcerInformation (BIOS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoOwb.jpg)

[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wyx6.jpg)

[Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g10BO.jpg)

[Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZP3v.jpg)

And, of course, if you need more information, ask for it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you have compatibility issues between the legacy (MBR) and new (UEFI) boot. If your new laptop cannot support legacy boot, I'm afraid there is no easy way out of this. In plain words: while legacy boot relies on the boot-loader in the boot-sector, that reads and executes a program starting in a particular location on the hard drive (LILO did that, GRUB v.2 is a bit smarter and is aware of the files in the particular partition, you just need to enable a module that handles a particular filesystem), UEFI does not need a boot sector. It needs a specific filesystem (FAT32) and looks for the file with a particular name in the EFI partition. The filename can be controlled from OS or from BIOS itself. In theory both can coexist - you can have a legacy boot-loader (GRUB) that boots a file from the EFI partition. Make sure you have the followng:

1. UEFI requires GPT partition system, you cannot have old MBR style partition, otherwise your new laptop won't boot
2. GRUB needs to understand and support FAT32 filesystem so it can find a kernel on the EFI partition (that needs to be formatted as FAT32)
3. I guess your old BIOS will require at least one bootable MBR partition, so  you probably need to enable backwards compatibility, sometimes called a hybrid GPT/MBR mode in fdisk/gdisk.
4. Then - it would be a matter of configuring GRUB to run the kernel from EFI and installing it in the boot-sector.

I have never done anything like that before, so I'm keeping my fingers crossed :)

Comment: Thank a lot for answering! But as I said, I dont really know much about this, so it's very difficult to understand your answer for me. I have googled 'hybrid gpt/mbr' and i found this https://www.slivermetal.org/2016/09/18/how-to-create-an-hybrid-uefi-gpt-bios-gptmbr-boot-usb-disk/ . You think I should follow it?

Comment: I guess :) as *I* said, I have never done this myself. Try it - this is more or less how I would tackle that problem.

Comment: But i have one question about it: can I do what that tutorial says from the proper hdd I want to make hybrid? Or should it be done from another one? And in that case, could be from the live disc?

Comment: You need to use the Live distro. System will not allow you to modify mounted partitions.

Comment: Great, thank you! I'll try it tomorrow.